# How to make a particular class file ARC - iphone

Tags: ios, publish-subscribe, xmppframework

I'm trying to integrate an additional ampp class file XMPPPubSub class from XMPP framework to my application. It says that we have to enable ARC for these files.

I have added -fobjc-arc flag against the file in Build Phases-> Compile Sources. 
The class has this code in it

```
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
#warning This file must be compiled with ARC. Use -fobjc-arc flag (or convert project to    ARC).
#endif
```

Even then i get this error

```
cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option "-fobjc-arc"
```

I have seen these links already

1) [How to require ARC in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379287/how-to-require-arc-in-a-class)

2) [How to add ARC for specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768176/how-to-add-arc-for-specific-file)

3) [How to enable ARC for a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523816/how-to-enable-arc-for-a-single-file)

But yet no luck. Am i missing something here?

Please give some suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly your project is set to use the wrong compiler. In your project settings, check that you are using Apple LLVM Compiler  and not LLVM GCC.

See this image from a demo project to know where to look for:

[image]

Comment: Yes... i guess you are right.I used Apple LLVM compiler 4.1.. But it gives other ARC errors like ARC Restrictions error which means now that the file is ARC converted right?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the compiler is treating all of your files will be treated as ARC files. So, you should set the `-fobjc-arc` on a per file basis (i.e., only on XMPPPubSub). In the Build Phases -> Compile Sources, find out where that file is and then set its ARC option on only for that one.

Comment: That I have done. In the same file it shows other ARC restriction errors.. guess i'll figure it out.. Thanks :)